# Avoid row collapse if click on checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table with rows that collapse/expand if clicking on the row, and each row has a checkbox. I need to avoid its collapsing or expanding if the click happens to be on the checkbox.
This is the jquery code:

```
$('tr').not('.main').hide();
    $('.main').click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.main').slideToggle(10);
    });
```

Comment: Post your html/css code and a fiddle example so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `event.stopPropagation()`;

```
$("tr").on("click", "[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @billyonecan: Yes, but i prefer doing it that way, so i can separate checkbox click in case i need to add some more actions to it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your click handler check the `event.target`. If it's a checkbox, `return true` so that the code isn't executed:

```
$('.main').click(function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
        return true;
    }

    $(this).nextUntil('tr.main').slideToggle(10);

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WzL3G/11/)

Comment: Your code is broken - if the target is checkbox, you're preventing an event entirely, and checkbox won't be checked/unchecked as a result.

Comment: @TwiStar Oops, thanks. Meant to return true, not false

Comment: Actually if we go that way i'd go reverse - execute code only if `e.target` isn't a checkbox. No need to premature returns or whatever.